# Different values of screen density

Tags: android, view, android-resources

I've defined an item in `values/dimen.xml` with the value `48dp`. When I set it to height of a view, in View Hierarchy Dump tool in eclipse, the real height of the view is `72`, which is `48*1.5`, and seem legit in my `hdpi` device (Nexus 7). **But**, when I load this value with this piece of code:

```
float d = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimension_name)
```

,`d` is 63, which is `48*1.3`. I am running my app on a `Nexus 7` which its real pixel density is `1.3`, according to [this](http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/). Where am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to load the dimension and get the real value (72)? or it is a bug or something?

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you define in your dimensions file? 48dp ?

Comment: 48dp, I corrected my post, thanks.

Comment: Ah ok makes sense now. What doesn't make sense though, is that the height of the view in the View Hierarchy is different than the height when calling it like you already tried. Is the View Hierarchy Dump and the dimension call from the same device?

Comment: Yeah, of course from the same devices.